how to check if value from a comma-separated string exists in string MySQL
I have a table with a column named tags. In this column, I have a comma-separated list like air conditioner, tv, fridge.
I want to check if any of the words in the comma-separated column exists in a string like
Is there an air conditioner in the room?
So, the query should return a match as in the column tags, the air conditioner value exists.
I was thinking of using find_in_set, but it will not work in this case as the logic should be reversed.
select * from products where find_in_set('Is there an air conditioner in the room?',tags) <> 0

UPDATE
I could use find_in_set by separating the string into words and then checking against the tags column, but it will not work for a combination like "air conditioner" as it will spit like air, conditioner.
MySQL version 5.7.44

Don't use a comma-separated list in the first place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Did you consider using full text search on text?

@SalmanA MySQL fulltext cannot use a column reference as the search pattern.

I have already tried fulltext but it didn't work

SELECT * FROM products
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REGEXP_REPLACE(tags, ', *', '","'), '"]'),
  '$[*]' COLUMNS(tag VARCHAR(20) PATH '$')
) AS j
WHERE LOCATE(j.tag, 'Is there an air conditioner in the room?');

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/ayNuWEqQ
This cannot be optimized with an index, just like any other substring-matching task.

The above solution with JSON_TABLE() requires MySQL 8.0 or later. MySQL 5.x is now past its end-of-life, but I understand some people have not upgraded. I'll leave this answer here for future folks who read this thread.

When I try your query I get this error
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(CONCAT('["', REGEXP_REPLACE(tags, ', ', '","'), '"]'), '$[]' COLUMNS(tag ' at line 2

Might be because I am using MySQL 5.7.44

Tried changing the version in your dbfiddle and I got the same error

Well, you're either going to have to upgrade to MySQL 8.0, or else change the table structure to avoid comma-separated lists. You've gotten two good answers on this thread. Good luck.

Agree with you... Will go with the version change as it is easy than the db structure. Thanks.

I have one more question. When I try to run the query I am getting this error #3141 - Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_table: "Missing a comma or ']' after an array element." at position 271.

Well, my dbfiddle demo works (see the link I included above). I don't know what your data looks like or what query you're trying.

Thanks Bill, just realized that the problem was a typo on my end.

I found an odd issue... sometimes in some queries throw this error #3141 - Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_table: "Invalid encoding in string." at position 429.
Do you have any clue what might be the problem?
I see that it's a problem related to encoding in string, but does that mean the encoding of the keywords in tags or the encoding of the field itself? The current field encoding is utf8mb4_general_ci the collation of the table after the upgrade to MySQL 8 become utf8mb3_general_ci

Again, I have no insight into what data values you are using or what code you're trying.

Here is a demo data https://dbfiddle.uk/85sJIh77 together with my query.
I cannot reproduce the error I am getting, but also the query in the sample is not catching anything. The data is not in English, but it is real data.

I tested and narrowed it down to a tab (^I) character trailing your JSON text. Remove the tab character and it works fine.

That did it. Removing all tabs fixed the issue. Thanks again Bill!

Don't use a comma-separated field in the first place. Normalize your schema by putting the tags into their own table with a foreign key pointing back to the products table.
CREATE TABLE product_tags (
    tag VARCHAR(100),
    product_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (tag, product_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
);

Then you can use
SELECT p.*
FROM products AS p
JOIN product_tags AS pt ON p.id = pt.product_id
WHERE LOCATE(pt.tag, 'Is there an air conditioner in the room?')


That would do but I cannot change the table structure

You can test it like this:
``` 
create table mytags (
  id int(11),
  tags varchar(64)
  );

insert into mytags values(1,"air conditioner, tv, fridge");

SELECT * from mytags;


```


| id | tags |
|---:|:-----|
| 1 | air conditioner, tv, fridge |

``` 
SELECT * FROM mytags WHERE FIND_IN_SET("air conditioner",tags);
```
| id | tags |
|---:|:-----|
| 1 | air conditioner, tv, fridge |

fiddle
Or remove always all spaces. Then you can find it with or without spaces Like:
```

SELECT * FROM mytags WHERE
 FIND_IN_SET(REPLACE("airconditioner"," ",""),REPLACE(tags," ",""));

| id | tags |
|---:|:-----|
| 1 | air conditioner, tv, fridge |

fiddle

That is fine, but there is no way to know how to separate words in a sentence. If we use white space as a separator it will separate the air conditioner into two words like air and conditioner. So this will not work unless I find some logic (splitting the string into meaningful pieces) that will work in all cases

@lStoilov - i have in my ANSWER

How does it help when the search string is is there an air conditioner in the room?, not simply air conditioner?

BTW, you shouldn't put a space after the comma separators. FIND_IN_SET() treats them literally.

@Barmer - thanks for the tip. This is my mistake
